# Two web storages on iOS with phonegap, one being backed up?

Tags: ios, cordova

One of my phonegap 2.8.1 apps just got rejected by Apple because it uses a bit over 5 MB in storage, and that is too much for iCloud. I assume they mean localstorage, which would be in line with how much data I store there. That localstorage is used for two things in my app:

- a) A key-value database with thousands of keys, this can be recreated
  from data files. It is accessed randomly.
- b) Settings and preferences that the user creates, this cannot be
  recreated and would benefit from iCloud backups

What I think I need to do is to use two different storages for this, one that is marked as "do not backup", and one that is marked as "do backup".

I see three possibilities for this:

1. Have two localstorages, how would I go about doing that? Would it
   be possible to just list the plugin twice with different parameters? Somehow tell iOS that
   only one of storages the should be backed up. How do I do this?
2. Use SQLStorage for one of them, and then somehow tell iOS that
   only one of the storages should be backed up. How do I do this?
3. Use a file to serialize the user preferences, and mark localstorage as "do not
   backup", how would I go about that? Somehow tell iOS that
   localstorage should not be backed up. How do I do this? (Edit: There is an [xml setting](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_project-settings_ios_index.md.html#Project%20Settings%20for%20iOS) for this in phonegap, BackupWebStorage, will come back with info if it functions)
4. Use a third party storage product for one of the databases, in that case, which?

I don't normally program in Objective C but can get a hold of a guy if I know exactly what to do. Had this been on Android I think I could have done it.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can mark particular files as "do not backup with iCloud" 2) Certain folders are marked to back up, like documents, and others not to back up, like Cache.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: Thanks, I just found that there is an xml setting in phonegap for not backing up localstorage, it is by default set to backup to icloud. I will come back and summarise when I have tested that the setting indeed works for a beta tester. "BackupWebStorage" http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_project-settings_ios_index.md.html#Project%20Settings%20for%20iOS

Comment: Using certain folders, I could put the user settings in a file in a folder where things do get backed up, as per their location.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just got info from one of the beta testers, and it seems that the BackupWebStorage setting in phonegap 2.8.1 does work. This means that option 3 is doable:

- Store the key-value data that can be recreated, in the localstorage, and
  mark all webstorage as not being part of a backup.
- Store the user preferences in a file that does get backed up

**Mark local storage as not part of the backup**

In the config.xml file set:

```
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
```

To check that it works, Apple recommends this way to check how much data you have put under the auspices of iCloud:

> - Install and launch your app
> - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
> - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
> - Check your app's storage

Do note that this cannot be done with a simulator, you need a real device.

**Create a file for user preferences**

Not tested yet, but phonegap has an api for it. From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW9):

> Critical data should be stored in the /Documents
>   directory. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your
>   app, such as user documents and other user-generated content

Phonegap has a [file API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File). Metadata can be set on the file:

> only the "com.apple.MobileBackup" extended attribute is supported. Set
>   the value to 1 to NOT enable the file to be backed up by iCloud. Set
>   the value to 0 to re-enable the file to be backed up by iCloud.